# Downloading files from server side script python

Tags: python, django

I have a python code which performs a GET request to a URL based on input and this is a file hosted on a URL, I am going to download this using this code:

```
import urllib.request

url = input()
download_file = urllib.request.URLopener()
file = download_file.retrieve('URL', 'Downloaded File')
```

How would I look at implementing this code onto my website, I'm thinking Django? never used it but from my research, this looks like the way forward. Does this sound like the way to do it, could someone give me some guidance of where to looks within there docs or alternative methods.

I assume I would have to host my script on a server and the input into the input box would be the input into the Python script and I would need to return the downloaded file to the user. Is that how it would be done?

Comment: I would suggest using libraries that work with your website, that will save you ton of work (dealing with django, etc).

Comment: +1 to Hamza suggestion. If you want to start small and learn as you need things Flask is a great choice. Django is also a great it comes with everything included.